# ¿Por qué todas las imágenes estáticas de medios en Django devuelven errores 404 al pasar a producción?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, apache

**CONTEXTO.** Python 3.9.4, Django 4.2.3, Apache 2.4.35

**ESTRUCTURA DE CARPETAS:**

```
test-media/
    testmedia/
        apps/
            myapp/
        media/
        static/
        templates/
        __init__.py
        asgi.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    venv/
    db.sqlite3
    manage.py
```

**SETTINGS.PY (resumido)**

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
ROOT_URLCONF = 'testmedia.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'testmedia/templates')],
    },
]
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'testmedia', 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "testmedia/static",
]
MEDIA_URL  = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'testmedia', 'media/')
```

**URLS.PY**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('testmedia.apps.volumen.urls'))
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**VHOST Apache**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/laragon/www/python/test-media"
    ServerName testmedia.local

    Alias /media/ D:/laragon/www/python/test-media/testmedia/media/
    Alias /static/ D:/laragon/www/python/test-media/testmedia/static/

    <Directory D:/laragon/www/python/test-media/testmedia/static>
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory D:/laragon/www/python/test-media/testmedia/media>
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory D:/laragon/www/python/test-media/testmedia>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
    ErrorLog D:/laragon/bin/apache/httpd-2.4.35-win64-VC15/logs/testmedia-error_log
    CustomLog D:/laragon/bin/apache/httpd-2.4.35-win64-VC15/logs/testmedia-access_log common

    <Directory />
        Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory "D:/laragon/www/python/test-media">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**PROBLEMA.** Con estas mismas configuraciones, en modo dev (`DEBUG=True`) funciona todo perfecto. Pero al pasar a modo prod (`DEBUG=False`) todas las imágenes de medios devuelven errores 404. He revisado de arriba a bajo la documentación y según yo todas las configuraciones están conforme la documentación, y nada parece funcionar. ¿Alguna idea? :(

De hecho tengo el mismo problema con los archivos estáticos tipo static (o sea los no media), pero si instalo y uso [Whitenoise](https://pypi.org/project/whitenoise/), este problema se soluciona (sólo para los archivos estáticos no-media).

Por supuesto no olvido ejecutar el collectstatic y migrar la DB, y todas mis imágenes están almacenadas perfecto en la carpeta a la que hace referencia MEDIA_ROOT.

Finalmente, cabe mencionar que este mismo proyecto lo he levantado en un servidor local en Windows, como en un servidor productivo en un Rhel 8 (con el mismo Apache, Django y Python 3.10), y en ambos casos el problema persiste.

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esto: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/1674/ Igual es de ayuda. Parece que cuando el debug está a `False` Django no se encarga de servir static files.